# Convert componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedPropsFromState

Tags: reactjs

I just want to know how I convert this function into the new one react recommends

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.onAuthComplete(nextProps)
    }
```

into

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(prevState, nextProps) {

}
```

**Full Component**

```
class AuthScreen extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.facebookLogin()
        console.log(this.props.token)
        this.onAuthComplete(this.props)
        
    }

   
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.onAuthComplete(nextProps)
    }


    onAuthComplete(props) {
        console.log(props);
        if (props) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('map')
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
           <Text> Welcome to the Auth Screen </Text>
        </View>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({auth}) {
    return {token: auth.token}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(AuthScreen)
```

Comment: can you share onAuthComplete function detail? Because getDerivedStateFromProps can access only static methods or variable.

Comment: Yeah I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

getDerivedStateFromProps can access only static methods or variables.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(prevState, nextProps) {
  this.onAuthComplete(nextProps);
}

static onAuthComplete(props) {
    console.log(props);
    if (props && props.navigation) {
        props.navigation.navigate('map')
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes so much sense thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  If your question is resolved, can you confirm this answer?